# How to solder this broken Gameboy Color part back on?

Tags: batteries, soldering, repair, metal

I'm trying to repair a GameboyColor where a part that held a battery broke off. I tried soldering it back on but it didn't stick. (I'm new to soldering)
I took some pictures, any feedback and advice is welcome.
Gallery:[**https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VraV.jpg**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VraV.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Did the whole part come off the board, or did the springy part break off?

Comment: @mike65535 The whole part came off.

Comment: If you get a bit of old mains lead and have a practice soldering the copper wire in that, it will make it a bit easier when you solder the actual part that needs mending. You'll get an idea of how long it takes the solder to melt and how much fumes you get from the flux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the solder did not stick, then your soldering technique was likely not correct. First, I would remove the old solder. Use a solder sucker or copper wick to remove the old solder. Clean the pad with isopropyl alcohol or contact cleaner. You could also add a bit of flux if you still have issues with getting solder to stick.

Once the pad is clean, ensure your soldering iron tip is clean and tinned. Heat the pad for a couple seconds, and apply solder to the pad (Not the tip of the iron!). Place the GBC part in place and heat up joint until the solder melts, keeping heat on the joint for another second or two. That should be it.

Comment: There might be considerable thermal mass to heat up so it might take a while for the necessary area (board AND battery terminal) to entirely heat up to proper temperature.

Comment: @mike65535 It is possible I misunderstood the question. I've done quite a few mods/repairs of video game systems, including GBC. If I recall correctly, my battery terminals were through-hole. Judging from his image, at least the top contact is a solder pad - so if the whole part came off (Rather than snapping the terminal somewhere) he should just be heating a small portion of the battery terminal to the pad.

Comment: If you want the solder to stick well, you'll need to heat the part to temperature, too.

Comment: @Felthry Thanks for the feedback, I'll update my original post to reflect that more clearly. The spring should have a small ear/tab. That should be placed on the pad and the joint heated. I only meant that the entire terminal will not require heating, which was how I interpreted the response from mike65535.